# To Retrieve data which doesn't have any entry in past 3 month

Tags: mysql, accounting

Table name: Transactions_accounting
purpose: to account every transactions for order_id with amount,datetime
I need to retrieve record which we didn't receive any payment for past 3 months.

I tried:

```
SELECT order_id 
   FROM transactions 
  WHERE account_datetime <= '2022-03-24' 
    AND status='success'
```

getting result 9789711,9809995. but I should get only 9789711, 9809995 received the payment on past month

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3opeX.png)

Kindly suggest me some queries for retrieve data where we didn't receive payment for past 3 months for about 100000 records

Comment: Post the table in textual form instead of image and your _"getting result 9789711,9809995. but I should get only 9789711, 9809995 received the payment on past month"_ description is a bit confusing so can you illustrate your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

First create a sub query with last payment date and compare it. Ex:
`select order_id from (select order_id, max(account_datetime) as last_date from transactions where status ='success' group by order_id) where last_date <= '2022-03-24'`